# Keras fails to load model weights when using MXNet backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mxnet

I am trying gap fill a half hourly time series of carbon fluxes. I want to use train-test-validate cross validation to identify the most parsimonious LSTM model by training a model with all available inputs and then pruning it until the score stops improving.  For each model, I'm using k-fold CV to split 90% train, 10% validate, and then in the model.fit(), splitting train further into a train and test set.  I'm using early stopping to help minimize run time and using ModelCheckpoint to save the best weights (the epoch with the lowest "val_loss").  Then I want to load those model weights and calculate the validation score (MSE) on the 10% of the data set aside for validation outside the model using the weights that performed best on test set.

Here is a working example of my code training an LSTM with 9 factors and 13 timestimes (the 6 hours leading up to each observation)

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import combinations
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor as MPR
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping,ModelCheckpoint
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.9
session = tf.Session(config=config)

def TimeShape(rolls,X1):
    X = np.zeros(shape = (X1.shape[0],rolls+1,X1.shape[1]))
    X[:,0,:] = X1
    if rolls > 0:
        for roll in range(0,rolls):
            X2 = np.roll(X1,(roll+1),axis=0)
            X[:,roll+1,:] = X2
    return(X)

def LSTM_Model(time_steps,inputs,load=None):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(12, input_shape=(time_steps+1,inputs),return_sequences=True,init='normal', activation='tanh'))
    model.add(LSTM(6,init='normal', activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(1, init='normal',activation='linear'))
    NUM_GPU = 1 # or the number of GPUs available on your machine
    gpu_list = []
    for i in range(NUM_GPU): gpu_list.append('gpu(%d)' % i)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',context=gpu_list) # - Add if using MXNET
    return(model)

class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.train_losses = []
        self.test_losses = []
    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.train_losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
        self.test_losses.append(logs.get('val_loss'))

class LSTM_Optimize:
    def __init__(self,Path,y_var):
#       **Read and prep Data Data**
        self.Master = pd.read_csv(Path,delimiter = ',',header = 0,na_values = -9999)
        self.Master = self.Master.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(self.Master['datetime'])))
        self.Master['DOY'] = self.Master.index.dayofyear*1.0
        self.Master['HR'] = self.Master.index.hour*1.0
        self.Data = self.Master[np.isfinite(self.Master[y_var])]
        self.Data = self.Data.interpolate().bfill()
        self.Data = self.Data.interpolate().ffill()
#       ** Nomralize Y variable**
#       ** Pipeline takes care of X, but not Y, I've foun the models work better when normalizing Y **
        self.y = self.Data[y_var].values
        self.YStandard = StandardScaler()
        self.YScaled = self.YStandard.fit(self.y.reshape(-1, 1))
        Yscale = self.YScaled.transform(self.y.reshape(-1, 1))
        self.y = np.ndarray.flatten(Yscale)
        self.Ytru = self.YScaled.inverse_transform(self.y.reshape(-1,1))

    def Run(self,Inputs):
        # Preparing the input data
        time_steps = 12   
        X = self.Data[Inputs]
        input_shape = len(Inputs)
        self.XStandard = StandardScaler()
        self.XScaled= self.XStandard.fit(X)
        Xscale = self.XScaled.transform(X)
        Xscale = TimeShape(time_steps,Xscale)
        Xscale = Xscale[time_steps+1:,:,:]
        self.y = self.y[time_steps+1:]


        ES = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.0, patience=25, verbose=1, mode='auto')
        CH = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='weights.hdf5',monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True)
        HS=LossHistory()
        MSE = []
        kf = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10,n_repeats=2)
        batch_size=25
        Mod = LSTM_Model(time_steps,input_shape)
        plt.figure(figsize = (7,7))
        for train,test in kf.split(Xscale,self.y):
            Mod.fit(Xscale[train],self.y[train],batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=1000,validation_split=0.1,
                    shuffle=True,callbacks=[ES,CH,HS],verbose=0)
            Y = Mod.predict(Xscale[test],batch_size = batch_size)
            Mod.load_weights('weights.hdf5')
            Y = Mod.predict(Xscale[test],batch_size = batch_size)
            MSE.append(metrics.mean_squared_error(self.y[test],Y))
            plt.plot(HS.test_losses,linestyle='--')
            plt.plot(HS.train_losses)

        print(Mod.summary())
        print(np.asanyarray(MSE).mean())

Path = 'FluxData.csv'
% matplotlib inline
start_time = time.time()
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    CH4_Model = ['Sedge','Shrubby','Temp','VWC','ustar','wind_speed','air_pressure',
             'PPFD_Avg','NR_Wm2_Avg','AirTC_Avg']
    y_var = 'ch4_flux'
    Model = CH4_Model
    Best = LSTM_Optimize(Path,y_var)
    Best.Run(Model)
    print()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

And here are a few rows of my dataset - the actual series has 1000's of observations

```
datetime,co2_flux,ch4_flux,ustar,wind_speed,AirTC_Avg,air_pressure,AirTC_Min,RH,PPFD_Avg,NR_Wm2_Avg,VWC,Temp,Sedge,Shrubby
7/11/2016 8:00,-0.337747167,0.011732699,0.404379747,3.887986435,15.07,101118.6513,15.03,92.7,414.2,225.1,0.5895,7.950660426,0.001292044,0.823794007
7/11/2016 8:30,-1.021087283,0.010256442,0.424094541,3.94983083,14.89,101144.0926,14.84,92.8,339.7,177.1,0.5895,8.24119905,0.001058732,0.826866339
7/11/2016 9:00,-0.146511388,0.008503355,0.456274817,4.687202214,14.71,101177.3176,14.63,93.4,354.4,183.7,0.5895,8.146344257,0.000474955,0.84272365
7/11/2016 9:30,0.144368521,0.009458078,0.462915317,4.810986576,14.27,101203.9191,14.2,93.3,370.2,188.4,0.5895,7.995179025,0.00147768,0.854715683
7/11/2016 10:00,1.471425801,0.014895985,0.47095652,5.098075355,13.7,101235.9171,13.62,94.3,462.9,233.9,0.5895,7.521166721,4.64E-05,0.871581919
7/11/2016 10:30,0.889911286,0.01564225,0.487227522,4.969666239,13.13,101277.0195,13.04,96,309.9,155.2,0.5895,7.923818563,8.14E-06,0.880709962
```

When I run this with a Tensorflow backed, everything goes smoothly and I get .  Howeverif I try to run it with a MXNet backend, it fails to load the save model weights and I get this traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-14c6597a2feb> in <module>()
    114     Model = CH4_Model
    115     Best = LSTM_Optimize(Path,y_var)
--> 116     Best.Run(Model)
    117     print()
    118     print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

<ipython-input-1-14c6597a2feb> in Run(self, Inputs)
     96                     shuffle=True,callbacks=[ES,CH,HS],verbose=0)
     97             Y = Mod.predict(Xscale[test],batch_size = batch_size)
---> 98             Mod.load_weights('weights.hdf5')
     99             Y = Mod.predict(Xscale[test],batch_size = batch_size)
    100             MSE.append(metrics.mean_squared_error(self.y[test],Y))

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py3.5.egg/keras/engine/topology.py in load_weights(self, filepath, by_name)
   2718             self.load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name(f)
   2719         else:
-> 2720             self.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f)
   2721 
   2722         if hasattr(f, 'close'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py3.5.egg/keras/engine/topology.py in load_weights_from_hdf5_group(self, f)
   2804                         weight_values[0] = w
   2805                 weight_value_tuples += zip(symbolic_weights, weight_values)
-> 2806             K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
   2807 
   2808     def load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name(self, f):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py3.5.egg/keras/backend/mxnet_backend.py in batch_set_value(tuples)
   2205     """
   2206     for p, w in tuples:
-> 2207         set_value(p, w)
   2208 
   2209 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py3.5.egg/keras/backend/mxnet_backend.py in set_value(x, value)
   2193     if isinstance(value, Number):
   2194         value = [value]
-> 2195     x.bind(mx.nd.array(value))
   2196 
   2197 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mxnet-0.11.0-py3.5.egg/mxnet/ndarray.py in array(source_array, ctx, dtype)
   1295                 raise TypeError('source_array must be array like object')
   1296     arr = empty(source_array.shape, ctx, dtype)
-> 1297     arr[:] = source_array
   1298     return arr
   1299 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mxnet-0.11.0-py3.5.egg/mxnet/ndarray.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    384                 _internal._set_value(float(value), out=self)
    385             elif isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, np.generic)):
--> 386                 self._sync_copyfrom(value)
    387             else:
    388                 raise TypeError(

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mxnet-0.11.0-py3.5.egg/mxnet/ndarray.py in _sync_copyfrom(self, source_array)
    556             print(self.shape)
    557             raise ValueError('Shape inconsistent: expected %s vs got %s'%(
--> 558                 str(self.shape), str(source_array.shape)))
    559         check_call(_LIB.MXNDArraySyncCopyFromCPU(
    560             self.handle,

ValueError: Shape inconsistent: expected () vs got (1,)
```

Why do I want to use MXNet?  It seems to be faster than tensorflow, and I will have to perform train-test-validation on many models with varying inputs and different #s of nodes and hyper-paramters.  I've been able to significantly boost the speed of keras models with a MXNet backend by using multiprocessing to train multiple different models in parallel.  However, using a tensroflow back end I get a thread-lock error when trying to do multiprocessing.

For context, I'm using Deep Learning AMI Ubuntu Linux - 2.3_Sep2017 (ami-d6ee1dae) environment on a p2.xlarge instance.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hey, did you figure it out?

Comment: Not with MXNet, I gave up on it and switched to tensorflow.  I figured out how to implement multiprocessing with tensorflow to train-test-validate models simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

MXNet backend LSTM layer uses MXNet's [bucketing module](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/how_to/bucketing.html) that requires declaring bucket sizes (length) statically, however, Keras and TF supports dynamic length. Hence, you are seeing issue with loading the model weights and shape mis-match.

Currently working on adding Keras2 support with MXNet backend, and this issue should be taken care in the Keras2.https://github.com/deep-learning-tools/keras/tree/keras2_mxnet_backend
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8697